# Beautiful Soup finds only half the wanted table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, I try to scrape the table named *'Germany, Kempten Average prices of Gouda'* which exists on this [page](https://www.clal.it/en/index.php?section=gouda_k), using python and BeautifulSoup. It should be as straight-forward as implementing something like the following block of code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web_page = 'https://www.clal.it/en/index.php?section=gouda_k'

page = requests.get(web_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

table = str(soup.find_all('table')[17])
```

Through trial end error I found that out of all the tables, the one that I want is the 17th. The problem is that it just scrapes the first two lines. If we check exactly what lives in the variable `table`, we see the following:

```
<table align="center" width="100%">

   THE CONTENTS OF THE TABLE UP TO THE SECOND LINE

</table>
```

But if we review the `page.txt`, the `</table>` tag is not after the second line, but in the end of the table, as one would expect.

**Question #1** : Why does bs4 finds a `</table>` tag where there should not be one?

**Question #2** : Any suggestions to actually manage to parse the entirety of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem was caused due to the `html.parser` feature.

You can use `html5` or `lxml` feature. But again these features have their limitations.

Here is the advantages and disadvantages of each parser library.
[https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#:%7E:text=This%20table%20summarizes%20the%20advantages%20and%20disadvantages%20of%20each%20parser%20library:)